# Memory considerations with sklearn classfier

Tags: classification, python, scikit-learn, numpy

I am trying to fit a `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier`. The [docs] explain that a matrix (rows - observations, columns - features). My observations are 700 000 short texts (tweets). My vocabulary is 1 000 000 unique words.

I tried doing `mat = np.zeros((num_tweets, num_words))` but that resulted in an allocation of 5TB (num_tweets * num_words * 4 bytes).

What is the recommended solution? A sparse matrix? Generators? Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Use sparse data types for sparse data

Today, English-language tweets have a character limit of 280 characters (previously, it was 140). This implies that a tweet can only contain a relatively small number of words, so a binary word-tweet matrix would have many 0 values. Using a sparse matrix will dramatically reduce your memory usage because you don't have to store all of the 0 values.

I'm not aware of a generator type that is compatible with `sklearn` classifiers. But the `sklearn` random forest classes do accept some sparse data types. [For more information, see the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html).